# Cutting thick wood veneer on band saw?

Tags: woodworking

Hey guys so this might be a stupid question but I am just a beginner, but can't I cut wood veneer on a band saw.

I glued 5 sheets of wood veneer together to make it thicker and stronger, but it' alternates in wood grain direction and in veneer type. I used paperback veneer and 2 ply veneer together. After I used a vacuum compressed to kee them flat while they dry. Now I need to cut them into smaller pieces, I'm fairly sure it would be fine to use a band saw, right?

Also I've made 3 large pieces of veneers but one of them came out a bit warped for some reason, is there a way to flatten it even after it's been glued up and thick?

Comment: You may want to take this question to the Woodworking Stack Exchange.

Comment: I have had good luck wetting single sheets and using a very fine blade. Wetting helps to reduce cracking. You may be able to steam the warped sheets if you used white glue and clamp the pices between plywood until dry.

Comment: Are you thinking to use the bandsaw to cut a thick board into thin sheets of veneer, or to cut an already-thin sheet of veneer into its final shape?

Answer (score 1):

Yep. The Band Saw would be best, since it cuts downward & will avoid any face chipping. If it's not currently cutting downward, for some bad reason, then you'll need to flip the band & therefore restore the band saw to normal & safe operation.

The warped piece might be scrap. But, you can try putting it in the oven or in your really hot attic or out in the Sun on something black. This will hopefully temporarily loosen the glue for a weighted compression or flattening. Possibly upside down with a central spacer to over-bend it backwards, so the new tension releases the old tension until dry again.